# Packet delay after route is added over new WiFi connection

Tags: linux, networking, routing, wpa-supplicant, wpa

### Network Setup

- STA is Ubuntu 18.04 (4.15.0-147-generic)
- 2x Intel 7620
- Each interface is connected to a different AP in the same subnet
- STA is streaming 1080p video over UDP (~15Mbits/s) using gstreamer
- Video is streamed exclusively over the WiFi one interface st a time, all other traffic uses a wired connection

### Problem

I control which WiFi interface streams the video using a static route to the receive pipeline for each interface

```
Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
<receiver IP>    _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   99     0        0 wlp1s0
<receiver IP>    _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 wlp2s0
```

In the above scenario, traffic is routed over `wlp1s0`. When I remove the route for `wlp1s0`, I see in `iftop` that traffic is then sent over `wlp2s0`.

I notice that there is a problem that manifests as one or two lost / delayed frames on the video receive pipeline if I reroute the video traffic over a connection that has not been used yet. Using the above scenario as an example, I start off with both interfaces authenticated, associated, and 4-way handshake complete, but the route for `wlp1s0` has a lower metric than `wlp2s0`, so no packets have been sent over `wlp2s0` yet. When I remove the route for `wlp1s0`, there is a very short blip in the video, then everything goes back to normal.

The strange thing is, after I experience this blip in the video and stay connected to the same APs, I can add and remove the route for `wlp1s0` repeatedly with absolutely no noticeable effect on the video. I've verified using `iftop` that I can flip flop which interface is active, and there isn't any effect on the video quality.

### Things I've looked at

I've run `wpa_supplicant` manually at the highest verbosity, and there are no relevant errors / warnings. I've also taken a look at the AP controller log, and there are no errors / warnings reported there. Using `sudo tcpdump -c 10000 -n -B 10240 -i wlp1s0` while I induced the blip in the video also didn't report any problems.

What else can I look at to diagnose and fix this issue?

### Update

I created a cgroup with a new routing table and a static route on `wlp1s0` to the video pipeline destination. I observed that if I push traffic over `wlp1s0` using

```
cgexec -g net_cls:cg1 iperf3 -c <receiver IP> -p 1234 -u -b 10M
```

right before I add the route for `wlp1s0` to the default table, there is no blip in the video. I guess what that means is that blips in the video is from a stale arp cache?

Comment: Random try: would the glitch be reproduced when switching again routes if you clear ARP caches on both sides (`ip neigh flush all` on Linux)?

Comment: That’s a good idea, I’ll be able to try tomorrow then report back

Comment: `ip neigh flush all` did not reproduce the glitch

Comment: Following the reverse logic I also tried adding static arp entries for each interface, but this didn't fix the problem either

Comment: Yes I was thinking about stale ARP. But you obfuscated a few settings that prevent good understanding. Normally (with Ethernet) you'd rather use aggregation (Linux bonding...) so the same MAC address stays in both places instead of trying to use routes to solve the failover problem, but I don't know if this works the same with the additional limitations from Wireless. And still, detection of a "carrier down" might be very fast with Ethernet, not so with Wireless.

Comment: I actually tried bonding the WiFi interfaces first. The problem is that when traffic is routed over the new connection, the AP boots the STA off because of an authentication error. I'm thinking there is some mismanagement of keys on the client side. The STA is able to reconnect in about 100ms, but the result is still some dropped video frames.